# Received HTTP code 302 from proxy after CONNECT While cloning a bitbucket repository

Tags: git, proxy, bitbucket

I'm trying to clone a repo using proxy.

I've already configured git with:

```
git config --global https.proxy http:\\proxyuser:proxypass@proxy.name.edu.co:8080
```

But when I type:

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/petsc/petsc petsc
```

It shows me the next error:

> Cloning into 'pflotran-dev'... fatal: unable to access
>   'https://bitbucket.org/pflotran/pflotran-dev/': Received HTTP code 302
>   from proxy after CONNECT

I think I did it all right. I have no idea what is happening.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Are you tried to clone using ssh address And then Try without proxy `git config --global --unset http.proxy`

Comment: Yes I've tried but I've got errors connecting to bitbucket. I blame the proxy.

I wonder if I configured it right or not, because it says "Received HTTP code 302 from proxy after CONNECT"

Comment: @RafaelBarónCastro use forward slash "/" and not back slash "\" and try again.... and please do let us know if something works!

Comment: I was getting 302s from git and it turned out to be a transient error.  I just did a fetch and a pull and retried the operation I was interested in, a push in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be a syntax error:

- A proxy with \ won't work: `http:\\proxyuser...`
- A proxy with // should work: `http://proxyuser...`

So try:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypass@proxy.name.edu.co:8080
git config --global https.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypass@proxy.name.edu.co:8080
```